# What is the significance of other sensates's names according to The Wachowskis?

Tags: character, sense8, the-wachowskis

In *Sense8*, it is said that The Wachowskis pick character names that carry a significance for their role and I got a interview where two actor answered it themselves:

> **Nuke the Fridge:** Did the Wachowskis tell you why they named her Nomi and what that name meant to them?
>
> **Jamie Clayton:** Yes. Lana and I had a really big talk about it. I won’t give the entire story but I’ll tell you it’s “know me.” Do I know me? Do you know me? Lana has this really amazing idea about knowing one’s own personal limits and knowing how far you can go, knowing what you will do. Do I know me? Do you know me? How far will I go for the people that I love. [src](http://nukethefridge.com/2015/06/05/sense8-roundtable-jamie-clayton-and-brian-j-smith/)
>
> ........
>
> **Brian J. Smith:** I love these name games. You see it in The Matrix. They choose names, even Will. The whole idea of Will Gorsky, the idea of someone who’s got this drive to act and to do, not just to be done to. It’s very central to Will’s character.

But what is the significance of rest of the six sensates according to The Wachowskis? How the meaning of there character name have significance for there role in the show?

Comment: Did you want the story line of each of these characters? Because I think I may have an answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that this can give you a brief explanation:

**[Nomi Marks](https://nameberry.com/babyname/Nomi)**:

beautiful, pleasant, delightful. This adorable cross cultural name updates Naomi and offers an accessible Japanese option. Strikes the right balance by being distinctive without seeming strange.

Significance:

It isn't exactly how she behaves within the film itself, she was chosen purely because her name is as described above-and she had the rigth mentality to be different from the other seven without acting strange. Nothing so significant here.

**[Will Gorsky](https://www.ancestry.com.au/name-origin?surname=gorski)**:

The name Will means helmet. Gorsky:

Polish (Górski) and Jewish (eastern Ashkenazic): habitational name for someone from any of numerous places called Góra, Górka, or Górki, from góra ‘mountain’, ‘hill’.

Significance:

What his name means is not specifically just for him, but his name applies to all of the sensates. They are strangers from all around the world, as the name **Gorsky** suggests. This is the connection his name has with the film.

**[Riley](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=WHat%20the%20name%20Riley%20means&oq=WHat%20the%20name%20Riley%20means&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i30k1l2.1416.6484.0.6611.26.19.0.0.0.0.525.3073.2-6j3j0j1.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..16.10.3069.6..35i39k1j0i67k1j0i20k1j0i131k1.JmfYSjAgV1s)**:

From the Old English ryge leah, meaning "wood clearing." It's also an adaptation of the Irish last name Reilly. Another meaning is "valiant."

Significance:

Because his name means **courage** as well as *wood clearing**, she accidentally dives deep into the drug trade. She also helps Will to knock Whispers out with a drug so then the two of them can escape into the woods.

*Finds that she cannot escape her tragic past and goes home to Iceland to confront it and reunite with her father, who is a famous Icelandic pianist*.

This is also a good explanation of her name being Riley, because she was courageous enough to confront her father and to help Will escape from Whispers.

**[Wolf Gang](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=WHat%20the%20name%20WolfGang%20means&oq=WHat%20the%20name%20WolfGang%20means&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1.76451.79869.0.79970.15.14.0.0.0.0.454.1809.0j1j2j1j2.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..9.5.1396...0j35i39k1j0i22i10i30k1.k5xVqjXqWpw)**:

Derived from the Germanic elements wulf meaning "wolf" and gang "path". Two famous bearers of this name were Austrian composer Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart (1756-1791) and German novelist and poet Johann Wolfgang von Goethe (1749-1832).

Significance:

His actions during the movie took an agressive path in the movie, including killing multiple people in the movie and being selfless as telling Kala that they can not be together. His name suggests aggressiveness and he was agressive in the movie.

**[Capheus](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=What%20the%20name%20%20Capheus%20means&oq=What%20the%20name%20%20Capheus%20means&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1.84706.91933.0.92080.17.14.0.0.0.0.342.2486.2-7j2.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..8.7.1869...0j0i8i7i30k1j35i39k1.oCN6RkALvZE)**:

The name Cepheus is a Greek baby name. In Greek the meaning of the name Cepheus is: The father of Andromeda in ancient Greek mythology.

Significance:

Capheus is the father of *adromeda* and a former *Greek God* and is also a constellation. His name also means *2 rulers*: **A matatu driver in Nairobi, and a passionate fan of Jean-Claude Van Damme who is trying to earn money to buy AIDS medicine for his mother. Capheus owns his bus matatu business with his best friend Jela.**

This suggests that he was a leader in both being a fan and being a driver, just like the God was. That is the significance of this character.

**[Kala](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=What%20the%20name%20Kala%20means&oq=What%20the%20name%20Kala%20means&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1j0i22i30k1l3.44101.46770.0.46893.12.9.0.0.0.0.295.1103.2-4.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..8.4.1102...0j35i39k1.5xJa8JPUGgo)**:

Indian Meaning: The name Kala is an Indian baby name. In Indian the meaning of the name Kala is: Black.

Significance:

Because Kala is a black person, the name very well suits her. There isn't really any behavioural aspects in this name (this is not to be taken as racism).

**[Lito](https://www.greek-names.info/lito-or-leto/)**:

A female Greek name which originates from the ancient years; the etymology of the name Lito is not exactly known, but it is believed that it derives from Greek ληθω (letho) which means “hidden, forgotten” or "tall".

Significance:

Lito lives up to his name because he was tall, he was not straight (as in sexually attracted) and had a boyfriend named **Hermando**. There isn't really much behavioural aspects to this name either as the meaning of the name can be applied to any of the three above, it happens to be *tall* in the movie. That is all it represents: being tall.

**[Sun](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=What%20the%20name%20Sun%20means&oq=What%20the%20name%20Sun%20means&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1l3.1408.3102.0.4427.7.7.0.0.0.0.348.1064.2-3j1.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.4.1064.zRfHj1Pks3Y)**:

The name Sun is a baby girl name. The name Sun comes from the Korean origin. In Korean the meaning of the name Sun is: Goodness.

Significance:

As she put herself in a spot for her father (because he asked her to) to be arrested by police, as sun is already looked down upon by their partners fro being a woman. This suggests *selflessness* for a crie she did not commit. She became unpopular in prison however, because she helped and was good towards a woman who was being picked on by the other inmates. The woman then wants to get revenge on the bullies, and Sun helps her but runs into an ambush. Sun manages to fend them off. So after this, her name portrays her cahracter as being selfless and good.

Comment: I don't want to know the plain meaning of the names but the significance of that meaning in context of the character.

Comment: Ahhh ok, sorry about that. I wasn't exaclty sure that is what you wanted. Tommorrow I will edit it so then you have an appropriate answer.

Comment: I tried making it more clear

Comment: not entirely done editing yet.

Comment: Editing is now done and complete.